# Tensor product of two symmetric algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

*Let $M,N$ be two $R$-modules. It is true that $\mathsf{S}_RM\otimes_R \mathsf{S}_RN\simeq \mathsf{S}_R(M\oplus N)$?*

In the case of finitely generated free module it follows from the non-canonical isomorphism $\mathsf{S}_RR^n\simeq R[t_1,\ldots t_n]$.

I want to believe that in the case of finitely generated module a possible approach may use generators and relations, i.e. my hypothesis is that the functor $\mathsf{S}_R(\_)$ is exact.

UPD. Trying not to use advanced machinery, only definition of functor and coproduct. Coproduct in $R\mathsf{Mod}$ is direct sum and in $R\mathsf{CAlg}$ is tensor product of algebras. Let $\mathscr{F}$ be forgetful $R\mathsf{CAlg}\to R\mathsf{Mod}$ then it is possible to establish $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathsf{S}_R M, A)\simeq \operatorname{Hom}(M,\mathscr{F}(A))$. And then it is possible to show via definition that $\mathsf{S}_R(M\oplus N)$ is coproduct of two symmetric algebras.

Comment: The tensor algebra functor has right adjoint, hence preserves, in particular, coproducts.

Comment: @Fabio: this is true but it doesn’t imply the desired result, which is false. The coproduct of algebras is the free product, not the tensor product.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan yes, I've made a mistake. Question will be fixed soon

Comment: @Mitya: yes, the revised statement and proof is fine now. Taking the symmetric algebra is a left adjoint and the tensor product of *commutative* algebras is the coproduct.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan what are counter-examples of the our statement's generalization for $\mathsf{T}_R(M)\otimes \mathsf{T}_R(N)$? Finite dimensional vector spaces may be such examles?

Comment: A stupid one. Let's notice that $\mathsf{T}_R R \otimes_R \mathsf{T}_R R\simeq R[x,y]$ but $\mathsf{T}_R(R^2)$ is a non-commutative ring.